# Error when attempting to set a map in Mongodb / mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have something like...

```
type Item struct {
  Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  Config map[string]interface{} `json:"config" bson:"config,inline"`
}

func (repository *ItemRepository) UpdateConfig(id string, config map[string]interface{}) {
  change := mgo.Change{
    Update: bson.M{"$set": bson.M{
      "config": config,
    }},
  },
}
```

But I get an error `Raw Unmarshal can't deal with struct values. Use a pointer.`. I'm not entirely sure what this means, or what's expected. Is it possible to just store 'loose' data as a sub-document?

Comment: use the pointer of `config` instead of `config` itself

Comment: Still the same error @simon_xia

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using `Update` instead of `FindId(id).Apply(change, nil)`.

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution.
if you were to use .Apply you should pass an interface.

say you have 


`type config struct {...}`

you should do 


**.Apply(change, &config{})**